# Polar Coordinate Axis Line Color Modification

Tags: javascript, colors, echarts

original template :https://echarts.apache.org/examples/zh/editor.html?c=bar-polar-stack-radial

I am unable to change the outmost axis line(outmost circle) color and would love to know how. [outmost axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJXqY.png)
i used dark mode on echarts website to turn the outmost line into greyish white.
[output using echart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRPGE.png)
would love the correct method to change that line color instead of using dark mode
any ideas would help, thank you

```
data = [
['大品牌青睐', 100, 'Business Agglomeration Degree',],
['商业核心', 50, 'Business Agglomeration Degree',],
['基础商业', 50, 'Business Agglomeration Degree',],
['城际交通 基础设施', 60, 'TrafficHub',],
['交通联系度', 50, 'TrafficHub',],
['物流通达度', 50, 'TrafficHub',],
['商业资源区域中心度', 50, 'TrafficHub',],
['消费活跃度', 50, 'Residents Vitality',],
['社交活跃度', 50, 'Residents Vitality',],
['夜间活跃度', 50, 'Residents Vitality',],
['出门新鲜度', 60, 'Lifestyle Diversity',],
['消费多样性', 50, 'Lifestyle Diversity',],
['休闲丰富度', 50, 'Lifestyle Diversity',],
['创新氛围', 50, 'Promised Future',],
['人才吸引力', 50, 'Promised Future',],
['消费潜力', 50, 'Promised Future',],
['城市规模与增长', 55, 'Promised Future',],
```

]

```
cats = {
'Business Agglomeration Degree': 'rgb(255,255,102)',
'TrafficHub': 'rgb(252,110,34)',
'Residents Vitality': 'rgb(194,76,246)',
'Lifestyle Diversity': 'rgb(255,20,147)',
'Promised Future': 'rgb(8,247,254)',
```

}

```
option = {
backgroundColor:'rgb(105,105,105)',
axisLabel: {
    color:'rgb(248,248,255)'  
},


lineStyle:{
    Color:'(255,250,250)'
},
timeAxis:{
    axisLine:{
      lineStyle:{
          color:'rgb(248,248,255)'}},
},
angleAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: data.map(function(d){return d[0]}),
    axisLine:{
        linestyle:{
            color:'#FFFAFA',width:(1),type:'solid',show:true,onZero :true}},
    splitLine:{
        linestyle:{
            color:'#FFFAFA',width:(1),type:'solid'}},
    
    
},
radiusAxis: {
    max:120,
    axisLine:{
      lineStyle:{
          color:'rgb(248,248,255)'}},
    axisTick:{
      lineStyle:{
          color:'rgb(248,248,255)'}},  
    minorTick:{
      lineStyle:{
          color:'rgb(248,248,255)'}},
     minorSplitLine:{
      lineStyle:{
          color:'rgb(248,248,255)'}},
    axisPointer:{
      lineStyle:{
          color:'rgb(248,248,255)'}},      
    axisLabel:{
      lineStyle:{
          color:'rgb(248,248,255)'}},   
    splitLine:{
      lineStyle:{
          color:'rgb(248,248,255)'}},  
    splitArea:{
      lineStyle:{
          color:'rgb(248,248,255)'}},
    tooltip:{
        show:false
    }
    
},

polar: {
},

axisPointer:{
    linestyle:{
        color:'#FFFFF0',width:(1),type:'solid'},
    crossStyle:{
        color:'#FFFFF0'},
    type:'line',
    snap:false,
    triggerTooltip:true,
    value:null,
    status:null,
    animation:null,
    

},

series: {
        type: 'bar',
        data: data.map(function(d){return d[1]}),
        coordinateSystem: 'polar',
        name: 'a',
        stack: 'a',
        emphasis: {
            focus: 'series'
        },
        
        itemStyle: {   
            normal:{  
                color: function (params){
                    return cats[data[params.dataIndex][2]]
                }
            },
            emphasis: {
                shadowBlur: 10,
                shadowOffsetX: 0,
                shadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
            }
        }
        
}, 



toolbox: {
    show: true,
    feature: {
        mark: {show: true},
        dataView: {show: true, readOnly: false},
        restore: {show: true},
        saveAsImage: {show: true}
    }
},
```

};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking the [documentation](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#angleAxis.axisLine.lineStyle.color), I found a way to change the color of the axis:

- Set the value to the `angleAxis.axisLine.lineStyle.color` property.

Code:

```
angleAxis: {
    type: "value",
    startAngle: 0,
    axisLine: {
      lineStyle: {
        color: "rgba(232, 13, 13, 1)" // This is the color to apply to the axis line.
      }
    }
  },
```

I also noted you had `linestyle`, it's `lineStyle` instead - note the uppercase.

This is the full code:

```js
var dom = document.getElementById("container");
var myChart = echarts.init(dom);
var app = {};

var option;



data = [
  ['大品牌青睐', 100, 'Business Agglomeration Degree', ],
  ['商业核心', 50, 'Business Agglomeration Degree', ],
  ['基础商业', 50, 'Business Agglomeration Degree', ],
  ['城际交通 基础设施', 60, 'TrafficHub', ],
  ['交通联系度', 50, 'TrafficHub', ],
  ['物流通达度', 50, 'TrafficHub', ],
  ['商业资源区域中心度', 50, 'TrafficHub', ],
  ['消费活跃度', 50, 'Residents Vitality', ],
  ['社交活跃度', 50, 'Residents Vitality', ],
  ['夜间活跃度', 50, 'Residents Vitality', ],
  ['出门新鲜度', 60, 'Lifestyle Diversity', ],
  ['消费多样性', 50, 'Lifestyle Diversity', ],
  ['休闲丰富度', 50, 'Lifestyle Diversity', ],
  ['创新氛围', 50, 'Promised Future', ],
  ['人才吸引力', 50, 'Promised Future', ],
  ['消费潜力', 50, 'Promised Future', ],
  ['城市规模与增长', 55, 'Promised Future', ],
];

cats = {
  'Business Agglomeration Degree': 'rgb(255,255,102)',
  'TrafficHub': 'rgb(252,110,34)',
  'Residents Vitality': 'rgb(194,76,246)',
  'Lifestyle Diversity': 'rgb(255,20,147)',
  'Promised Future': 'rgb(8,247,254)'
}

option = {
  backgroundColor: 'rgb(105,105,105)',
  axisLabel: {
    color: 'rgb(248,248,255)'
  },
  lineStyle: {
    Color: '(255,250,250)'
  },
  timeAxis: {
    axisLine: {
      lineStyle: {
        color: 'rgb(248,248,255)'
      }
    },
  },
  angleAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: data.map(function(d) {
      return d[0]
    }),
    axisLine: {
      lineStyle: {
        width: (1),
        type: 'solid',
        show: true,
        onZero: true,
        color: "rgba(210, 25, 25, 1)" // This the color of the axis line, in this case, red.
      }
    },
    splitLine: {
      linestyle: {
        color: '#FFFAFA',
        width: (1),
        type: 'solid'

      }
    },
  },
  radiusAxis: {
    max: 120,
    axisLine: {
      lineStyle: {
        color: '#FFFAFA',
        width: (1),
        type: 'solid',
        show: true,
        onZero: true
      },
      lineStyle: {
        color: 'rgb(248,248,255)'
      }
    },
    axisTick: {
      lineStyle: {
        color: 'rgb(248,248,255)'
      }
    },
    minorTick: {
      lineStyle: {
        color: 'rgb(248,248,255)'
      }
    },
    minorSplitLine: {
      lineStyle: {
        color: 'rgb(248,248,255)'
      }
    },
    axisPointer: {
      lineStyle: {
        color: 'rgb(248,248,255)'
      }
    },
    axisLabel: {
      lineStyle: {
        color: 'rgb(248,248,255)'
      }
    },
    splitLine: {
      lineStyle: {
        color: 'rgb(248,248,255)'
      }
    },
    splitArea: {
      lineStyle: {
        color: 'rgb(248,248,255)'
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      show: false
    }
  },

  polar: {},

  axisPointer: {
    linestyle: {
      color: '#FFFFF0',
      width: (1),
      type: 'solid'
    },
    crossStyle: {
      color: '#FFFFF0'
    },
    type: 'line',
    snap: false,
    triggerTooltip: true,
    value: null,
    status: null,
    animation: null
  },
  series: {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data.map(function(d) {
      return d[1]
    }),
    coordinateSystem: 'polar',
    name: 'a',
    stack: 'a',
    emphasis: {
      focus: 'series'
    },
    itemStyle: {
      normal: {
        color: function(params) {
          return cats[data[params.dataIndex][2]]
        }
      },
      emphasis: {
        shadowBlur: 10,
        shadowOffsetX: 0,
        shadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
      }
    }
  },
  toolbox: {
    show: true,
    feature: {
      mark: {
        show: true
      },
      dataView: {
        show: true,
        readOnly: false
      },
      restore: {
        show: true
      },
      saveAsImage: {
        show: true
      }
    }
  },
};

if (option && typeof option === 'object') {
  myChart.setOption(option);
}
```

```html
<!--
    THIS EXAMPLE WAS DOWNLOADED FROM https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar-polar-stack-radial
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: 100%">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body style="height: 100%; margin: 0">
  <div id="container" style="height: 100%"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
</body>
```